# React Native - difference between parameters in tag and styles

Tags: button, react-native

I'm trying to change the background color of a button with React-native.

I can't figure out why this works

```
<Button
 color="#841584"
 title={item.title}
/>
```

but this does not

```
<Button
  style={styles.buttonStyle}
  color="#841584"
  title={item.title}
/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttonStyle: {
        color:"#841584"
    }
});
```

I tried with either `color` or `backgroundColor` attribute, none of them work

Why are these different from one another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Button`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html#props) component for react-native doesn't have a `style` prop. Because of this the style you gave doesn't apply.

> **Props**
>
> - onPress
> - title
> - accessibilityLabel
> - color
> - disabled
> - testID
> - hasTVPreferredFocus

It is basically a custom component built in react-native. You can create yours with using [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html) or [`TouchableNativeFeedback`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablenativefeedback.html). For inspiration, you can look at the [source code for `Button` component](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js).